# EF not updateing a particular object on SaveChanges

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I'm having a very weird bug, that only seems to happen on a particular item I'm trying to update in the DB, using entity framework.

Here is my code:

```
var shoppingCartItem = GetShoppingCartItemById(shoppingCartItemId);
shoppingCartItem.Quantity = newQuantity;
_context.SaveChanges();
```

and this is the method that gets the item from the DB before updateing:

```
public ShoppingCartItem GetShoppingCartItemById(int shoppingCartItemId)
        {
            if (shoppingCartItemId == 0)
                return null;


            var query = from sci in _context.ShoppingCartItems
                        where sci.ShoppingCartItemId == shoppingCartItemId
                        select sci;
            var shoppingCartItem = query.SingleOrDefault();
            return shoppingCartItem;
        }
```

This code works on some items, but doesn't on a particular one I'm testing with now. If I check the state of the object (using _context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(shoppingCartItem)) after changing the property Quantity it's Unchanged :(

Has this ever happens to any of you? Any idea why this happens, or what could be causing this?

Comment: Are you sure that a new value of quantity is different?

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar problem while passing the data object to a view, then getting it back again - in this case it breaks the link to the datacontext. this shouldnt happen in this case, but setting the EntityState to Modified and re-attaching it worked for me, it may be worth trying for you.

```
var shoppingCartItem = GetShoppingCartItemById(shoppingCartItemId);
shoppingCartItem.Quantity = newQuantity;


_context.Entry(shoppingCartItem).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;

_context.SaveChanges();
```

Note however that this only works with EF4.1 - I had to update to 4.1 just to get an easy way to edit items!

Comment: the link to the context isn't broken, otherwise GetObjectStateEntry would report Detached, not Unchanged.

Comment: for the record, you can mark an object as dirty in any EF vesion: _context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(object, System.Data.EntityState.Modified);